# Problem wiring a 3-way lamp switch

Tags: switch, replacement, lamp

I just bought a new 3-way lamp switch/socket to replace an old one that had burned out, along with 2 new 3-way bulbs.  I'm almost certain I installed it correctly (ribbed - neutral, smooth - hot) but its only lighting at the medium level. I tried both bulbs with the same result.  Is it a bad switch/socket or is there something else I should be trying?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try another three-way lamp.

Three-way lamps have two filaments. One on for low, the other on for medium,and both on for high.

The screwshell is the neutral and the center button and outer ring are energized together for high. If you have a voltage tester, with the lamp switch on high,  you can carefully test from the center button to the outer shell. And then test from the ring to the outer shell. If you get 120 volts both times the switch is good. If not replace the switch.

If the switch is good it must be a bad lamp.

Good luck and stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you did indeed wire it correctly, but that the socket is bad.  If it wasn't wired then you would not get anything at all, even on medium.

If you have another 3-way lamp, you can test the bulbs to be sure it is not them.

If not, then try reversing the wires just to convince yourself that isn't the problem.

But in the end, from what is said here, it really does sound like you will end up returning that socket for replacement.